# Why do my items go left when you hover more of them simultaneously?

Tags: html, css, web, navigation, addeventlistener

I have a navigation on the right side of the page, and I made an animation where when you hover on a button it enlarges and shows the page name.

```js
// This is the JavaScript code where I make the Buttons Wider:
document.querySelectorAll(".nav-button").forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener("mouseover",
 () => {
    elem.querySelector(".nav-hover").style.width = "300%";
}));

document.querySelectorAll(".nav-button").forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener("mouseout",
 () => {
    elem.querySelector(".nav-hover").style.width = "";
}));
```

```css
.navigation {
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}

.navigation .buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
}

.button-el {
    height: 65px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.button-el i {
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: 28px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.nav-hover {
    z-index: -1;
    transition: width .5s ease-out, opacity 0s, all 1s;
    position: relative;
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    float: right;
    background-color: var(--dark1);
    border: var(--accent1) 3px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
    <div class="nav-button button-el home">
        <div class="active"></div>
        <div class="nav-hover">
           <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-button button-el home">
        <div class="active"></div>
        <div class="nav-hover">        
            <i class="fa-solid fa-user-large"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-button button-el home">
        <div class="active"></div>
        <div class="nav-hover">        
            <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think that the cause might be in the Javascript since the .buttons DIV moves when you activate very fast multiple `addEventListener` (mouseover and mouseout).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `.navigation .buttons` selector:

```css
.navigation .buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
}
```

It seems like what did change it was the `x` in `translate(x, -50%)`. Now it looks like this:

```css
.navigation .buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 67%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%) !important;
}
```